# Talend - how to select rows from a table where the load time is after the date/time in another table

Tags: talend

I have a staging table in Snowflake with a load datetimestamp.  I also have a separate table with a load datetimestamp that i need to reference back to the staging table.  I only want to select the data from the staging table where the datetime is after the last table load in my second table - so only new entries.

I can get the max date from my second table but I don't know which option to use to restrict the data retrieved from the staging table.  I don't have a specific primary key to join back on - it is a combination of a large number of fields so i'd rather not try to join them together if I can help it.

I've set a Global Variable which works okay and now want to use it in my Query but it doesn't seem to work so i'm wondering if i'm using it correctly? My query is as follows:
"SELECT TOP 20 * FROM RAW_SALES_GK WHERE to_varchar(LOADDATETIME_GK, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss') > '"+globalMap.get("GKLastLoadDate")+"'"

I attempted to put quotes around the date as it errors without it. Although I am now getting data back it isn't following the rules of my query.

[image]

Comment: could you show us your job design , and it  is preferable to let us know what you tried as far also your fields name and prefered output ! so we could help

Comment: an approach can be to fetch the table max from second table store it in variable, then `select * from stg where datetime>global_variable`. Please show ur current trails and job design

Comment: Thanks - the option to store the date as a variable should fix the issue.  It must be the one and only thing I hadn't thought of

Comment: I've set a Global Variable which works okay and now want to use it in my Query but it doesn't seem to work so i'm wondering if i'm using it correctly?  My query is as follows:                            "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM RAW_SALES_GK WHERE to_varchar(LOADDATETIME_GK, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss') > '"+globalMap.get("GKLastLoadDate")+"'"                                                                          I attempted to put quotes around the date as it errors without it.  Although I am now getting data back it isn't following the rules of my query